# How can I define a "Duration" variable in XAML? (WPF) Allow me change the variable in backstage

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Duration x:Key="duration"></Duration>
    <Storyboard x:Key="progressBarAnimation" TargetName="arc">
        <PointAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point" Duration="{StaticResource duration}">
            <PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M 0 -125 A 125 125 0 0 1 0 125 A 125 125 0 0 1 0 -125"/>
            </PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </PointAnimationUsingPath>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

How can I set a variable that allow me to change the variable in the backstage like:
((Storyboard)Animation.Resources["duration"]).Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3170877

Comment: I would rather use binding to a code-behind variable. Its a lot more practical in my experience

Comment: `(Storyboard)Animation.Resources["duration"]` does not make sense, and it is unclear what `Animation` is supposed to be here. In the UserControl's code behind, you would write `((Storyboard)Resources["progressBarAnimation"]).Duration = new Duration(...)`. The Duration resource is redundant.